# Разбить список по парам Python

Tags: python, list

Есть список - [1, 4, 6, 8, 11, 34...]. Нужно получить [[1,4], [6, 8], [11, 34]...] Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой самый оптимальный способ разбить по парам? Через генератор не могу сообразить, опыта пока мало. Спасибо!

Comment: оптимальный по какому показателю? Не бывает абстрактно "оптимальный".

Comment: [[spisok[x], spisok[x+1]] for x in range(0, len(spisok),2)]

Comment: Самый короткий, я могу написать функцию, но она будет громоздкой, мне кажется, что можно сделать это более лаконично.

Comment: @strawdog блин, так просто, спасибо! Напишите как ответ, отмечу!

Comment: len(spisok)-1, чтобы на нечетной длине не споткнуться

Comment: @MBo благодарю за добавление!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можете сделать это списковым включением:

```
res = [[spisok[x], spisok[x+1]] for x in range(0, len(spisok)-1,2)]
```

Comment: `[spisok[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(spisok), 2)]`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> @>>> lst = [1, 4, 6, 8, 11, 34]
> @>>> list(zip(*[iter(lst)] * 2))
> [(1, 4), (6, 8), (11, 34)]
> ```

[Документация по zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Tips and tricks:
>
> - The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed. This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n, strict=True)`. This repeats the same iterator n times so that each output tuple has the result of n calls to the iterator. This has the effect of dividing the input into n-length chunks.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[1, 4, 6, 8, 11, 34]
print(list(map(lambda x,y:[x,y],l[::2],l[1::2])))
```

---

```
[[1, 4], [6, 8], [11, 34]]
```